# TFS 2010 Build Dependency folder

Tags: build-definition, build-dependencies

I have a solution which has references to various dependencies. The dependency dlls are all stored in a folder as shown in the folder structure below. The solution below builds and runs fine in Visual Studio. The files have all been checked into TFS with the same folder structure. I've created a build definition in TFS 2010, mapping the $(SourceDir) to the TestApp folder. The 'Projects to build' is set to TestApp.sln.

On queueing a new build, I receive a number of 'Type 'xxx' is not defined' errors, where 'XXX' refers to a type in one of my dependency dlls. I suspect that my 'Dependencies' folder and the dlls within it, are not getting copied down from TFS, even though the $(SourceDir) is set to it's parent folder.

How do I get the build to copy these dependencies from the location in source control into wherever TFS's build agent compiles my project?

### Folder Structure

Root TestApp/
    Dependencies/ -> (folder contains my dependency dlls)
    Projects Folder -> (which contains my bin directory, my .cs files etc)
        TestApp.sln -> (The solution file)

Answer (score 0):

With `tfs` you need to make sure that:

- The `specific version` property is set to `true`
- If you want to make sure the DLLs are copied over make sure the property `copy local` is also set to `true`

Make sure you `build your solution` and then `check in`.